# Permission denied? when I set permissions for a file only for groups , what step am I missing

Tags: command-line, permissions

I have set so that only groups can read and write.

I have made a file in `/home/alice` (Alice is part of `red`).

Bob is also part of group `red`.

When I cd into the `/home/alice/file1` with Bob, I can see the file.

But I get permission denied when I run: `cat file1`

Is there a step I am missing to allow groups to read/write. The permissions are good and Alice and Bob are part of the same group.

Comment: Please provide the results of these commands in your post: `groups Alice`, `groups Bob` and `stat /home/alice/file1`

Comment: Does it work for you: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/linux-file-permissions ?

Comment: Please note that capital letters matter, so it's important if the usernames are Alice/Bob or alice/bob.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you set the group ownership of `/home/alice/file1` to `red`. To do this, run:

```
sudo chown alice:red /home/alice/file1
```

And view the permissions and ownership with:

```
stat /home/alice/file1 | grep 'Access'
```